# A way to just display one line in KML file on Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, kml

When I [load my KML file into Google Earth](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http://rioleo.org/dev/gps/data/2013-01-09T04-36-27Z.kml), it shows me there's two lines and I can toggle between them:

[image]

but I can't seem to display just one of the lines using something like:

```
var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://rioleo.org/dev/gps/data/2013-01-09T04-36-27Z.kml');
ctaLayer.setMap(map);
```

Is there a way to just load one specific line from a KML file? If not, how does one toggle each line?

Comment: Instead of using a static KML-file you may use a serverside script that accepts parameters and delivers  a filtered KML  regarding to the supplied parameters

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to put each line in a separate KML `<Folder>` and use `<open>` 0/1

[KML Reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#open)

Comment: I can't modify the KML file. Is there a way around it without modifying the file?

Comment: Not that I know of.  You could modify a third party KML parser to handle the gx:Track data (I know [geoxml3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/) doesn't parse that, I don't think [geoxml-v3](http://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) does), or you could write your own KML parser that does what you want.